# JSF - *.taglib.xml - attribute default value

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, facelets, eclipse-indigo, content-assist

I am facing a strange issue in JSF; The taglib.xml which I am trying to use for my jsf facelets; I am not sure how to set attribute default value in case of facelets so I tried [this alike way](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkhwv.html) (see code):

```
<tag>
<tag-name>ball</tag-name>
...
    <attribute>
        <name>color</name>
        <default>green</default>
        <required>false</required>
        <type>java.lang.String</type>
      </attribute>
...
</tag>
```

but I am really not sure cause seems like eclipse 3.7 content assist in case of **having this default element** doesn't work so I cannot use ctrl+space :(

So my question is... how really to set facelet default attribute value and if the `<default></default>` is correct then how to make my content assist work again 'cause, as I can remember, previously with no `<default-value></default-value>` it worked fine?

Thanks

Comment: About content-assist, my answer would be upgrade Eclipse... seriously ;-] (on Luna and Mars assist in this case is working for sure)

Comment: @EmilSierżęga no, I mean in case of jsf what `<attribute/>` element should I use to set default attribute value 'cause I am a bit confused :X Is it `<default>` or `<default-value>` or... ? give me a tip

Comment: So, yes I may confirm content assist doesn't want to parse taglib.xml if it has `<default>` or `<default-value>` attribute element :P I've just removed all defaults back and namespace becomes available again... So is it really content assist issue or I just must use another attribute element to have default value? Comment please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emm... After some testing I may confirm that `<default>` and `<default-value>` do make possible to set default attribute value *(it is pretty clear watching generated html)* but having those elements in ***.taglib.xml** make impossible to use eclipse 3.7 content assist :P

So probably, yes, it is some eclipse content assist issue...

p.s. I am still searching the issue coming exactly from so feel free to comment...